# obiee Cannot find logical table source coverage for logical columns

Tags: repository, obiee

I try to make some changes in the repository of an OBI 11g installation. 
I have a fact table who counts the positions in the departments.
I have a department table and a departmentDH table. 
The department and departmentDH are linked to the fact table with the deptId (both). 
In the logical layer I have a logical table and two LTS (logical table sources). One for the data of department and one for the data of departmentDH.

When I make an analysis with data of departments, data of departementsDH and the fact, everything goes fine. When I delete the fact in my analysis I get the error: "Cannot find logical table source coverage for logical columns".

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Counter question: How do you expect the engine to navigate between those two dimensions? I do not know how your business model is built in detail but probably your dimensions have nothing to do with each other and the query goes astray since a non-applicable fact table is used.

You can never to pure dimension-only queries across multiple dimensions!

If that specific fact table is supposed to be used in all cases where there is a doubt then you must set an implicit fact column for your Subject Area:

https://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/obis/implicit_fact_column